# How to send a GitHub Pull Request to multiple repos

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a project on GitHub, and I forked it to a second repository.

There is still work done on the repo that I forked from, but the changes I make to the first repo should also be applied to the forked one.

How can I push a pull request to both of them at the same time? Or is that impossible to do in a simple way?

If it is, is there a simple alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, GitHub pull requests only target a single repository.

Pull requests are only relevant when you are communicating with other people.  Since both repositories are yours, you can just execute a `git pull` or `git merge` command on your local machine to merge whatever branches you want to merge.  Then use `git push` to push the changes up to GitHub if you want.

Also, I recommend that you simplify this setup and just use a single GitHub repository with multiple branches.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Good to know it's not something I can do.
I didn't write it in my question, as I didn't think it was that important, but there will be others contributing so I'll have to use pull requests.